# Bash, get value from json line

Tags: bash, sed, awk, json

**System**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-27-lowlatency #28-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Aug 20 20:33:37 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Issue**

I have input file.

```
{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}
```

How can I get only this output (some cols)?

```
"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918"
```

No `jq` or other apps, I need just bash `sed` or `awk`, or some basic commands, I don't have admin rights to install it.

**I tried**

I tried `cut`, but there is a problem with delimiter `,` (sometimes are in `"`).

Thanks.

Comment: Only real solution: ask the server admin to install the proper tools for you.

Comment: Why not install jshon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"' | \
grep -E '^"(code|name|is_action|action_from|action_to)"' | \
tr '\n' ',' | \
sed 's/,$//'
```

*Details*:

- `grep -o '"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"'` find all `"key": "value"` pairs and prints them on separate lines;

Example:

```
echo '{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}' | grep -o '"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"'
```

Output:

```
"code": "01333457004"
"name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015"
"note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ"
"sel_unit": "Kus"
"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ"
"unit": "L"
"EAN": "4867601700052"
"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;"
"is_action": "1"
"action_from": "20190905"
"action_to": "20190918"
"ordered_from": "20190126"
"ordered_to": "20190830"
"shelf_id": "1030542"
```

- `grep -E '^"(code|name|is_action|action_from|action_to)"'` filters only needed keys.

Output:

```
"code": "01333457004"
"name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015"
"is_action": "1"
"action_from": "20190905"
"action_to": "20190918"
```

- `tr '\n' ','` replace new line to comma.

Output:

```
"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918",
```

- `sed 's/,$//'` removes last extra comma.

Output:

```
"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918"
```

*Full example*

Command:

```
echo '{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}' | grep -o '"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"' | grep -E '^"(code|name|is_action|action_from|action_to)"' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//'
```

Output:

```
"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918"
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation what you script is doing and how this solves the question.

Comment: @SimonSudler Your comment echoed my thoughts a couple of days ago. Answer has been revised and I've upvoted.

Comment: grep -o '"[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*"' find all "key": "value" pairs and prints them on separate lines;


This does not behave as expected if the JSOn has a key `id`

Comment: @SuryaPandian can you get example?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A JSON
a=$(
  grep -Po '\{.*\{\K(.*?)(?=\}\})' example.json |
  grep -Po '(^|,)\"\K(.*?)(?=\":)'
)
for b in $a; do
  JSON[$b]="$(grep -Po "\"$b\": \"?\K.*?(?=(\"?,\"|\}\}))" example.json)"
done


echo ${JSON[@]}
echo ${!JSON[@]}
echo ${JSON[name]}
```

or if you just want the values:

```
grep -Po '\{.*\{\K(.*?)(?=\}\})' example.json | grep -Po "\".*?\": \"?\K.*?(?=(\"?,\"|$))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the `,` delimiter fails, you can use `:` delimiter with `cut`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: ParseJSON
# PATH: $HOME/askubuntu/
# DESC: Answer for: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174505/bash-get-value-from-json-line
# DATE: September 16, 2019

Line='{ "article": {"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","note": "ČERV VÍNO EVROPA VÝCH OSTATNÍ","sel_unit": "Kus","unit_price": 229.0,"category": "ČERVENÉ,POLOSLADKÉ","unit": "L","EAN": "4867601700052","unit_volume": 0.75,"producer": null,"tax": 21.0,"text": "Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;Alazanis Valley 2015;Gruzie,Kachetie;červené polsladké;750ml;16°C;","is_action": "1","action_from": "20190905","action_to": "20190918","ordered_from": "20190126","ordered_to": "20190830","shelf_id": "1030542","is_outlet": 0}}'

Code=$(echo "$Line" | cut -d':' -f3)
Code="${Code%,*}"                           # Remove ,"name"
Name=$(echo "$Line" | cut -d':' -f4)
Name="${Name%,*}"                           # Remove ,"note"
IsAction=$(echo "$Line" | cut -d':' -f15)
IsAction="${IsAction%,*}"                   # Remove ,"action_from"
ActionFrom=$(echo "$Line" | cut -d':' -f16)
ActionFrom="${ActionFrom%,*}"               # Remove ,"action_to"
ActionTo=$(echo "$Line" | cut -d':' -f17)
ActionTo="${ActionTo%,*}"                   # Remove ,"ordered_from"

echo '"code":'"$Code,"'"name":'"$Name,"'"is_action":'"$IsAction,"'"action_from":'"$ActionFrom,"'"action_to":'"$ActionTo"
```

I called the script `ParseJSON` and this is it's output:

```
$ ParseJSON

"code": "01333457004","name": "ALAZANIS VALLEY 2015","is_action": "1","action_from":  "20190905","action_to": "20190918"
```